# actix_web pass config to handlers

Tags: rust

I'm writing an API server and want to read in a configuration file and pass that info to the request handlers. I'm having trouble getting Rust to allow that to happen.

```
let cfg = Arc::new(read_config());
let server = HttpServer::new(|| {
    App::new()
        .wrap(middleware::Logger::default())
        .service(web::resource("/api/files").route(web::get().to(move || {
            list_files(cfg.clone());
        })))
        .service(fs::Files::new("/", "client/public").index_file("index.html"))
});
```

The error I'm currently getting is

```
56 |       let cfg = Arc::new(read_config());
   |           --- captured outer variable
...
60 |               .service(web::resource("/api/files").route(web::get().to(move || {
   |  ______________________________________________________________________^
61 | |                 list_files(cfg.clone());
62 | |             })))
   | |_____________^ cannot move out of captured variable in an `Fn` closure
```

How should this be done? What's the correct way to pass a variable to a request handler?

Comment: Any chance you could add the definition of `list_files` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have 2 levels of closures. The first one is the argument to HttpServer::new(), which is non-moving: it captures a reference to cfg, which you then try to move into the second closure, web::get().to().

If you create a clone in the first closure, you can move that into the second, like this:

```
let cfg = Arc::new(read_config());
let server = HttpServer::new(|| {
    let cfg = cfg.clone();
    App::new()
        .wrap(middleware::Logger::default())
        .service(web::resource("/api/files").route(web::get().to(move || {
            list_files(cfg);
        })))
        .service(fs::Files::new("/", "client/public").index_file("index.html"))
});
```